# prolog - Add elements from terms in a List of Lists

Tags: database, prolog

I want to add elements recursively to my list of lists from a database.

```
employee(1, max, 1500).
employee(2, peter, 2100).
employee(3, tom, 3900).


bigearners([]).
bigearners( [Head|Lists]):- employee(Id,Name,Salary), append([Id,Name,Salary],[], Head), bigearners(Lists).
```

He creates lists like this: `[[1, max, 1500], [1, max, 1500], [1, max, 1500]`, 
but I want `[[1, max, 1500], [2, peter, 2100], [3, tom, 3900]]`. I guess it's not possible in a recursive way? I cannot find a not-recursive solution.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a builtin like findall/3

```
bigearners(L) :- findall([A,B,C], employee(A,B,C), L).
```

or use an accumulator:

```
bigearners(L) :- bigearners([],L), !.

bigearners(S,L) :-
 employee(A,B,C),
 H=[A,B,C],
 \+ memberchk(H,S),
 bigearners([H|S],L).
bigearners(L,L).
```

PS: `append([Id,Name,Salary],[], Head)` is more usually written like `Head = [Id,Name,Salary]`